# incompletely download of pgp file from ftp sever using apache.commons.net

Tags: java, ftp, pgp

I'm trying to transfer a pgp file with apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient, result seems successfully, but when I want to convert it to a txt file I encounter to this error:
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=20)

and when I check the exact size of downloaded file, I notice that it's size is about 1KB less than original file.

here is the code for downloading file:

```
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Localfilename);
            InputStream inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(remoteFileDir);
            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, fos);
            fos.flush();
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(fos);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
            boolean commandOK = ftpClient.completePendingCommand();
```

can any one understand what is mistake with my way or code?

[edited] noted that the original file decode (convert to txt)successfully, so the problem occures while downloading file.

[edited2] I run the program in my windows desktop and download file in windows, no problem for decode, and I understand that when I run my program with linux server this problem appears!

Comment: can you get the int value returned by IOUtils.copy and check if it equals the number of expected bytes?

Comment: I suppose the relevant bits of your code is missing. Could it be that you are trying to transfer a binary file but the FTPClient is set to transfer text files - FTPClient.setFileType(...) ?

Comment: @jarnbjo what should I set filetype to be when I want to transfer pgp file?

Comment: @Narges: What about reading the documentation? Setting it to FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE may solve your problem.

Comment: @GuyBouallet How can I get the number of expected file dynamicly?

Comment: @Narges int b = IOUtils.copy(inputStream, fos);

Comment: Have you checked the downloaded file content (instead of only size)? If you are getting a pgp key, some keys are even less than 1KB!

Comment: One thing that I don't see mentioned: when you transfer the file with a regular FTP client rather than your Java code, the decryption does succeed? It would be such a shame if the file is broken to begin with or you need a specific public key to decrypt it.

Comment: @Gimby key is not neccessory for downloading file!

Comment: ... no, but aren't you getting that error while decrypting the file? You are not answering my question in any way either.

Comment: @Gimby yes I get the error while decoding the downloaded file, but when I decode the original file in my server no error and no problem occur.

Comment: Add such relevant information to the question, not in a comment. Because you can decrypt the file prior to downloading it, the problem is indeed almost guaranteed to happen during the transfer. At this point to see what is going on I'd probably compare the original file to the broken file with a hex editor to see what the exact difference is. Added/changed bytes at the start, missing bytes at the end... seeing what is broken in the downloaded file can help to identify where the problem originates.

Comment: @Gimby Ok, I add it tnx, I open both file in hex editor about 100 line 0f 10880352 line of file reduce in downloaded version

Comment: @GuyBouallet  I add some new information to my question, please review it, thanks.

Comment: The new symptoms you describe are typical of ASCII vs binary file management. I would join @jarnbjo and suggest you to double check the setting of your file type transfer. Make sure you have this line executed before you start the transfer: ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

Comment: I wonder why some one vote me down?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem!
The problem was with addressing the remote path, a silly mistake!
so If any one has this problem recheck and recheck again the addresses.